# Alias for mipmap launcher icon

Tags: android, drawable

Is it possible to somehow make alias for mipmap icon? For example we have icon named icon_app but in our lib we use ic_launcher (as it should be). So for drawables you are able to create reference with `values/drawables.xml`

I tried with following approach:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item name="ic_launcher" type="mipmap">@mipmap/icon_app</item>
</resources>
```

but it seems its not working i tried naming it both drawables.xml and mipmaps.xml, it seems it always tries to reference it from drawable instead of mipmap folder?

Comment: "as it should be"...Why? Why not just change the name in the manifest to match `icon_app`?

Comment: Because i am referencing it from the code and i expect it to follow material design guidelines.

Comment: The material design guidelines tell you what to name your assets? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: Even though I have posted a solution below I hope that the bounty gets a few more eyes on this in case there are other factors that I have not identified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further attempts show that the code originally posted works fine when compiled onto device, but is just not recognised by Android Studio.

I was hoping to alias the system default launcher icon, and this seems to work:

```
<resources>
    <item name="test_alias" type="mipmap">@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon</item>
</resources>
```

...as do these:

```
<resources>
    <mipmap name="test_alias">@android:mipmap/sym_def_app_icon</mipmap>
    <mipmap name="test_alias2">@mipmap/ic_test</mipmap>
</resources>
```

...where `ic_test` is a "normal" mipmap in my `res/mipmap` resources folder.

---

To explain the use case in my situation, this above code is in a library project. The `test_alias` mipmap is declared in the library so that I can use it to put up a `Notification`.

But the intention is that the developer using the library would be able to override this icon with their own launcher, or other icon of their choosing by adding something like this into their own code, overriding the library definition:

```
<resources>
    <mipmap name="test_alias">@mipmap/ic_launcher</mipmap>
</resources>
```